# How to combine two columns of dataset in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a spark dataset like this:

```
> df.show()
+------+------+
| No1  | No2  |
+------+------+
| 001  | null |
| 002  | 002  |
| 003  | 004  |
| null | 005  |
+------+------+
```

I want to get a new column *No3* which contain values from column *No1* and *No2*, the condition is that copy *No1* if it has a value, else if it is null, use value from *No2*

```
+------+------+------+
| No1  | No2  | No3  |
+------+------+------+
| 001  | null | 001  |
| 002  | 002  | 002  |
| 003  | 004  | 003  |
| null | 005  | 005  |
+------+------+------+
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is **coalesce**.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("001", null),
  ("002", "002"),
  ("003", "004"),
  (null, "005")
)).toDF("No1", "No2")

val resultDf = data.withColumn("No3", coalesce($"No1", $"No2"))

resultDf.show
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the column `No1` for `null`. If its `null` then take the value from `No2`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
  ("001", null),
  ("002", "002"),
  ("003", "004"),
  (null, "005")
)).toDF("No1", "No2")

val resultDf = data.withColumn("No3", when($"No1".isNull, $"No2").otherwise($"No1"))

resultDf.show
```

Outpout:

```
+----+----+---+
|No1 |No2 |No3|
+----+----+---+
|001 |null|001|
|002 |002 |002|
|003 |004 |003|
|null|005 |005|
+----+----+---+
```

Hope this helps!